# Is this linear time or quadratic time? Using the same loop to iterate more than once

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

This is a hacky implementation of multiple pointers to find out if the array contains unique values. But I did so in a way that loops through it multiple times, skipping the OG pointer.

Is this linear or quadratic?

```
function uniqueAll(arr) {

let i = 0
for (let j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    console.log(`i: ${arr[i]} j: ${arr[j]}`)

    if (j === i) continue;

    if (j === arr.length - 1 && i < arr.length - 1) {
        i++
        j = 0
    }
    if (arr[j] === arr[i]) 
        return false
}

return true
}
```

And yea, I know it could be as simple as:

```
let isUnique = (arr) => [... new Set(arr)].length === arr.length
```

I'm exploring other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quadratic, O(n<sup>2</sup>). Your j counter increments until you reach the end of the array, so n times, but then you increment i and reset j to 0, starting again until i also reaches the length of the array. This is equivalent to nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

For an array with all unique items, it will run a loop for every item. So, the worst case complexity is definitely quadratic.